# Consequences of bipartite perfect matching not in NL?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, space-bounded, matching, conditional-results

> Are any significant consequences known of $\text{BPM} \not\in \textsf{NL}$?

---

I'm interested in the status of the following well-studied decision problem, in particular whether it is known to be in $\textsf{NL}$:

> **Bipartite Perfect Matching (BPM)**
>   *Input:* bipartite $2n$-vertex graph $G$
>   *Question:* does $G$ contain a [matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29) with $n$ edges?

Maximum Bipartite Matching is the version where the required size of a matching is given as part of the input.
By [Chandra-Stockmeyer-Vishkin](https://doi.org/10.1137/0213028), this is equivalent to BPM via $\textsf{AC}^0$-reductions, and these problems are hard for $\textsf{NL}$ via $\textsf{AC}^0$-reductions.

Recall the following sequence of inclusions (see the [Zoo](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo)):
$$\textsf{L} \subseteq \textsf{UL} \subseteq \textsf{NL} \subseteq \textsf{NC}^2 \subseteq \textsf{RNC}^2.$$

Looking at a more general problem, *maximum* matching for *general* graphs is in $\textsf{RNC}^2$, by [Mulmuley-Vazirani-Vazirani](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02579206) ([preprint](http://http.cs.berkeley.edu/~vazirani/pubs/matching.pdf)), and according to Allender-Reinhardt-Zhou this problem was (in 1999) not known to be in NL.
The latter paper also shows that BPM is in a nonuniform version of $\textsf{SPL}$, but $\textsf{SPL}$ is not known to be comparable to $\textsf{NL}$.
(The Zoo also claims that BPM is in $\textsf{coRNC}$ by [Karloff](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02579264), although it is not obvious to me how this follows from the results in Karloff's paper.)

All of the usual approaches to finding a maximum bipartite matching are polynomial-time.
Moreover, these algorithms have polynomial time bounds of quite low degree.
In particular, an $O(n^{2.5})$ time upper bound follows from the reduction of Hopcroft-Karp and Karzanov to maximum flow.
So it is not impossible that BPM (and perhaps even maximum matching) is in $\textsf{NL}$.

However, all the approaches I've looked at seem to be rather space-intensive.
The usual algorithms essentially keep track of subsets of the vertices, and therefore seem to require something like $\Omega(n)$ bits (although proving such a bound rigorously seems likely to be difficult).

Looking at a more specific problem, if the input graphs are further restricted to be *planar* as well as bipartite, then Planar BPM is in $\textsf{UL}$ and hence $\textsf{NL}$, by [Datta-Gopalan-Kulkarni-Tewari](https://doi.org/10.4230/LIPIcs.STACS.2012.254).

So BPM is $\textsf{NL}$-hard, but is in some complexity classes "not much larger than" $\textsf{NL}$, and is in $\textsf{NL}$ for restricted classes of bipartite graphs.
It therefore seems reasonable to ask: if $\text{BPM} \not\in\textsf{NL}$, would anything interesting follow?

Comment: btw, the "proof" showing Planar BPM in UL from DGKT is buggy. The part of the proof that shows it is in NL is however correct.